# Matrix become (3,) instead of (6,3) in Python Numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix

```
BPC=[BRad.*cos(BC)' BRad.*sin(BC)' zeros(1,6)']
```

Here is my MATLAB code that I convert into Python:

```
BPC=np.transpose(np.array([BRad * np.cos(BC),BRad * np.sin(BC),np.zeros((1,6))]))
```

MATLAB gives a (6,3) matrix and Python gives a (3,) matrix. What causes that?

Comment: What's `BC`,`BRad`? Use minimal sample data to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Maybe the `np` matrix is a vector of `(3,)` vectors, each with shape `(6,)`?

Comment: Add `dtype=float` on the end of the outer `np.array` call, and you'll get a more useful error message

Comment: BC and BRad local variable @Divakar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are getting a vector of three elements, the first two being vectors with six elements, and the last a matrix with 1x6 elements. Numpy can't "flatten" those into a single matrix.

```
>>> BRad = 1
>>> BC = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
>>> np.transpose(np.array([BRad * np.cos(BC), BRad * np.sin(BC), np.zeros((1,6))]))
array([ array([ 0.54030231, -0.41614684, -0.9899925 , -0.65364362,  0.28366219,
        0.96017029]),
       array([ 0.84147098,  0.90929743,  0.14112001, -0.7568025 , -0.95892427,
       -0.2794155 ]),
       array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])], dtype=object)
```

Instead of `np.zeros((1,6))`, try just `np.zeros(6)`

```
>>> np.transpose(np.array([BRad * np.cos(BC), BRad * np.sin(BC), np.zeros(6)]))
array([[ 0.54030231,  0.84147098,  0.        ],
       [-0.41614684,  0.90929743,  0.        ],
       [-0.9899925 ,  0.14112001,  0.        ],
       [-0.65364362, -0.7568025 ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.28366219, -0.95892427,  0.        ],
       [ 0.96017029, -0.2794155 ,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: Note that there are various discussion within numpy about eventually disabling the `object`-array-as-fallback behaviour - which would cause the original code to raise an explicit error, rather than do something surprising